# Como fazer um array de objetos?

Tags: c++, array, objetos

Como fazer um *array* de objetos? Estou tentando mas não estou obtendo êxito, me retorna um erro:

> linha 26 [Error] no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Time'
>   and 'int')

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Time.h"
using namespace std;


int apaga_espaco(ifstream &tab, Time t)
{
    string nome="gremio";
    int saldo=0;
    int vit=1,i;

    string s;
    char N;
    while (tab.good())
    {
        i++;
        getline(tab, s);
        s.erase(0,29);
        N=s.find(':');
        s.erase(0,N+6);

        return 0;
        t[i].set_name(nome);
    }
}   


int main()
{
    Time *t;
    t=new Time[20]; 
    ifstream tabe;
    char N;
    string s;
    tabe.open("Tabela.txt", ios::in);

    if (!tabe.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Arquivo nao encontrado, erro fatal!";
        exit(1);
    }

    apaga_espaco(tabe,*t);
}
```

Comment: desculpa me enganei na hora de marcar, já consertei.

Comment: Não tem problema. Agora você tem pode votar em tudo o que quiser no site. Lembrando que votar não é a mesma coisa que aceitar. Voto não é exclusivo. Pode dar em tudo o que quiser, mesmo em outras perguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código não faz nenhum sentido. E ele está um pouco desorganizado, o que dificulta entender o que está fazendo. Tem muita coisa solta, coisas não fazem nada útil. Fica difícil tentar fazer algo minimamente coerente. Mesmo acertando o que está perguntando ainda ele estaria repleto de problemas. Eu consertei algumas coisas, mas o código ainda está sem sentido.

A maior mudança foi usar `Vector` no lugar de *array*, afinal está usando C++ e o uso de *array* deve ser evitado. Não use técnicas de C em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


void apaga_espaco(ifstream& tab, vector<time_t> t) {
    string nome = "gremio";
    int saldo = 0;
    int vit = 1, i = 0;
    string s;
    char N;
    while (tab.good()) {
        i++;
        getline(tab, s);
        s.erase(0, 29);
        N = s.find(':');
        s.erase(0, N + 6);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<time_t> t(20); 
    ifstream tabe;
    char N;
    string s;
    tabe.open("Tabela.txt", ios::in);
    if (!tabe.is_open()) {
        cout << "Arquivo nao encontrado, erro fatal!";
        exit(1);
    }
    apaga_espaco(tabe, t);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/FileName2.cpp).

Comment: eu não conhecia esse Vector, valeu pela dica.